# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{5^{n+1}-4^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{5^{n+1}-4^n} $

This limit should be 5, but I can not figure out a way to handle the sum under the sqrt...

Comment: $$ 5^n <5^{n+1}-4^n< 5^{n+1}$$

Comment: You may factor out to get  $$\sqrt[n]{5^{n+1}-4^n} = \sqrt[n]{5^n\left(5-\left(\frac45\right)^n\right)} = 5\sqrt[n]{5-\left(\frac45\right)^n}$$